# complete directory names with fixed depth in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I am writing a completion function where at some point I use `_files -W $somevar -/` to complete sub directories of `$somevar`. For simplicity of the question let's say it's `$HOME/.local/lib` and I have subdirectories for different python versions in there and actually want to complete python versions for which I have a `$HOME/.local/lib/` directory:

```bsh
_files -W $HOME/.local/lib -/
```

and the directory tree looks something like

```
.local
├── lib
│   ├── python3.5
│   │   └── site-packages
│   │       ├── somepackage
│   │       ├── somepackage-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
│   │       ├── someotherpackage
│   │       └── someotherpackage-1.0.11-py2.7.egg-info
│   ├── python3.6
│   │   └── site-packages
│   │       ├── somepackage
│   │       │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── somepackage-0.1-py3.6.egg-info
│   │       ├── someotherpackage
│   │       │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── someotherpackage-2018.4.16.dist-info
...
```

If I use the above completion for `mycommand <TAB>` the suggestions are now `python3.5/` and `python3.6/` with the trailing slash inserted by the tab completion and once I picked one version, the completion further suggest `python3.5/site-package`. This is insofar correct behaviour as these are actually existing directories. For my use case, I don't want to go down the directory three, but only complete directories directly in $HOME/.local/lib. Is there an easy way to complete directories without completing into them with builtin completion functions? Or should I use glob expressions `$HOME/.local/lib/*(/)` and strip off the parts that I don't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_files -W $HOME/.local/lib -/ -S "" -F "*/*"` does the job: `-S ""` to suppress the addition of a suffix `/`, and `_F "*/*"` excludes subdirectories (via [`_path_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fpath_005ffiles) and [`compadd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd))).

`-F` causes the `ignored-patterns` style to be ignored, which is a minor downside of this approach. There may be a better way.